# Echo mysql results in a loop?

Tags: php, html, algorithm, mysqli

I am using turn.js to make a book.
Every `div` within the 'deathnote' `div` becomes a new page.

```
<div id="deathnote"> //starts book
<div style="background-image:url(images/coverpage.jpg);"></div> //creates new page
<div style="background-image:url(images/paper.jpg);"></div> //creates new page
<div style="background-image:url(images/paper.jpg);"></div> //creates new page
</div> //ends book
```

What I am doing is trying to get 3 'content' (content being a name and cause of death) `divs` onto 1 page, and then generate a new page.

So here is what i want:

```
<div id="deathnote"> //starts book
<div style="background-image:url(images/coverpage.jpg);"></div> //creates new page
<div style="background-image:url(images/paper.jpg);"></div> //creates new page
<div style="background-image:url(images/paper.jpg);"> //creates new page but leaves it open
<div> CONTENT </div>
<div> CONTENT </div>
<div> CONTENT </div>
</div> //ends the page
    </div> //ends book
```

Seems simple enough, however the content is data from a MySQL DB, so i have to echo it in using PHP. Here is what i have so far

```
<div id="deathnote">
    <div style="background-image:url(images/coverpage.jpg);"></div>
    <div style="background-image:url(images/paper.jpg);"></div>
    <div style="background-image:url(images/paper.jpg);"></div>
    <div style="background-image:url(images/paper.jpg);"></div>
    <div style="background-image:url(images/paper.jpg);"></div>
    <div style="background-image:url(images/paper.jpg);"></div>
        <?php
$pagecount = 0;
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'passw', 'DB');

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}

$sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT *
    FROM `TABLE`
SQL;

if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}
//IGNORE ALL OF THE GARBAGE ABOVE. IT IS SIMPLE CONNECTING SCRIPT THAT I KNOW WORKS
//THE METHOD I AM HAVING TROUBLE WITH IS BELOW
 $pagecount = 0;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ //GETS THE VALUE (and makes sure it isn't nothing
echo '<div style="background-image:url(images/paper.jpg);">'; //THIS OPENS A NEW PAGE
while ($pagecount !== 3) { //KEEPS COUNT OF HOW MUCH CONTENT DIVS IS ON THE PAGE
                        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ 


//START A CONTENT DIV
echo '<div class="content"><div class="name">'  . $row['victim'] . '</div><div class="cod">'  . $row['cod'] . '</div></div>';
//END A CONTENT DIV
                            $pagecount++; //UP THE PAGE COUNT
                        }
                                                }
                        $pagecount=0; //PUT IT BACK TO 0
echo '</div>'; //END PAGE
}

$db->close();
?>
    <div style="background-image:url(images/backpage.jpg);"></div> //BACK PAGE
</div>
```

At the moment i seem to be causing and infinite loop so the page won't load. The problem resides within the `while` loops.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance guys. :)

Comment: Please change second result set variable name $row to $rowCheck like that.

Comment: @ChinnuR Hey Dude, just did the change and no dice. However i think you may be onto something. with the first $row, instead of actually getting content from the DB can i simply leave it in the DB check if there is something there or not, and then let the second $rowcheck fetch the content?

Comment: From the PHP code what is your expected output? can you please mention the required output.

Comment: @ChinnuR The expected output is to print a victim name ($victim) and cause of death ($cod). 
I just want to print 3 names and COD's on 1 page, and then create a new page, amd print 3 names and cod's untill there is no more in my DB.

Answer (score 0):

Please run below code in your local instance first and confirm is below one is your expected concept. after that you can change your result set and let me know,

```
  <?php 

       $Numbers = range(1, 25); // change your result set here 
       $Limit = 3;
       $i=0;
       foreach($Numbers as $number){

            if($i==$Limit){
                    echo "<hr>"; // new page
                    $i=0; // reset the limiter
            }

            echo $number; // Values to be displayed

            $i++;
        }             
      ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've rewritten the loop for you, the loop now iterates through your entire database and places the opening div and closing div when required.

```
<div id="deathnote">
<div style="background-image:url(images/coverpage.jpg);"></div>
<div style="background-image:url(images/paper.jpg);"></div>
<div style="background-image:url(images/paper.jpg);"></div>

<?php
$pagecount = 0;
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'passw', 'DB');

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}

$sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT *
    FROM `TABLE`
SQL;

if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}

$pagecount=0;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
if($pagecount==0){ echo '<div style="background-image:url(images/paper.jpg);">';}
echo '<div class="content"><div class="name">'  . $row['victim'] . '</div><div class="cod">'  . $row['cod'] . '</div></div>';
if($pagecount==2){echo '</div>';}
$pagecount++;
if($pagecount==3){$pagecount=0;}
}
//this page count closes the last div (page) if you have less than three entries in it
if($pagecount==1||$pagecount==2){echo '</div>';}
$db->close();
?>
    <div style="background-image:url(images/backpage.jpg);"></div> //BACK PAGE
</div>
```